# Shortcuts for multiline C/C++ macros in eclipse editor

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, ide

I am writing a C program in Eclipse editor. My C program requires me to write a multi-line macro. I want to write a code like:

```
  #define my_Macro()        \
    struct my_Struct        \
    {                       \
        int a;              \
        float b;            \
    };                      \
```

But as the macro is large so I have to make sure that I insert a `\` at end of each line (for compiler to know that macro is continued).  So my question is: Does eclipse/CDT provides any way such that `\`  is automatically inserted till the point the code is part of macro?

Comment: One problem is, how should the editor know you're *done* with the macro?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. More importantly, if that macro is not paramterized, **WHY** would you do this?

Comment: @kdopen - Macro here in the example is not paramterized but the one in my code has parameters.

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry didn't got you.

Comment: Short answer is "no".   As hinted by Joachim Pileborg, the IDE would somehow need to recognise the end of the macro, and NOT add the last `'\'`.    Most code does not involve writing macros, so an IDE which insisted on placing a `'\'` at the end of every line would be exceedingly unpopular.

Comment: Please refrain from using macros.  If you need to reuse a structure or class, place into a header file.  If you need a function as a macro, make it inline.  **Macros Are Evil**

Comment: BTW, use the `C` tag for C language topics and `C++` tag for C++ topics.  I recommend removing the C++ tag since you stated you are programming in C.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - My assignment demands writting a Macro. I removed the C++ tag. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @MayankJain good move. It's nice that you are practicing. ;)

Comment: @gsamaras - I was checking few more things. I accepted it now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No***, there is no such built-in functionality from Eclipse.